# Cannot add app to Crashlytics

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I am using Android Studio and recently migrated to a new development machine. I have 2 working apps and am trying to add a new one. Crashlytics gives me the instructions which I follow and then it tells me to launch the app and says: Waiting. This goes on forever and nothing happens even when the app runs.

> 05-28 17:25:46.551    4828-4828/com.example I/Crashlytics﹕
>   Initializing Crashlytics 1.1.13.29 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ . 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .     |  | 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .     |  | 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .     |  | 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .   \ |  | / 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .    \    / 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .     \  / 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .      / 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ . 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ This app relies on Crashlytics.
>   Configure your build environment here: 05-28 17:25:46.561
>   4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕
>   https://crashlytics.com/register/55ee776e42323322e98d26bc634da9f89917c/android/com.example
>   05-28 17:25:46.561    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ . 05-28
>   17:25:46.561    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .      /\ 05-28
>   17:25:46.561    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .     /  \ 05-28
>   17:25:46.566    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .    /    \ 05-28
>   17:25:46.566    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .   / |  | \
>   05-28 17:25:46.566    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .     |  |
>   05-28 17:25:46.566    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .     |  |
>   05-28 17:25:46.566    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ .     |  |
>   05-28 17:25:46.566    4828-4828/com.example E/Crashlytics﹕ . 05-28
>   17:25:46.571    4828-4828/com.example E/MainLogger.start﹕ Could
>   not log:
>       This app relies on Crashlytics. Configure your build environment here:
>       https://crashlytics.com/register/55ee776e432233d26bc634da9f89917c/android/com.example

Clicking on the link, loads crashlytics site but then says at the bottom right:
Alert
Sorry, the app could not be located.

Anyone has an idea how to add the new app to Crashlytics?

Comment: Alex here from Fabric. It'd be super helpful to dig into your other project files i.e. AndroidManifest and build.gradle, and to also look at other logs. Probably best to handle this through our support channel: support@fabric.io. Once we figure out what's going on with your specific scenario, I can post the answer here!

Comment: Thanks Alex. I posted all details via email.

Comment: Alex: how long does it take to get an answer? We need to launch the app and are awaiting it. Also, why doesn't the link to setup the app work? After all, it should not depend on the grade and manifest file. It's simply a link.

Comment: Just sent you a response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could not get a resolution from Crashlytics so switched to Parse.com. It seems to be working fine (will test further and post if any issues). We will migrate all projects to Parse as it seems to have a simple integration which works for multi-projects.